# PHP + MySQL Database Insert Each Line

Tags: php, insert

I know I've seen this on Stack Overflow before, but not sure how I would put it to use for myself. So basically I'm creating a generator. All I need done, is to figure out how to insert a new row into my database.

So basically, I have a textbox & submit button, when I click the submit button each line in the textarea will be inserted as a whole new row in the database.

`

```
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="insert">

        </textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Enter" name="submit" />
```

`

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (value1, value2)...`

Comment: Give us some code on the HTML form at least.

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop to loop over the inputs, and put the values into the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I've added the little bit of HTMl.. I'm just testing this for now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table called `tblname` with column `text`, and you're sending the form value to `$_POST['insert']`. Using `mysqli` (and `pdo` is really similar):

```
//authenticate to $conn
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tblname (text) VALUES (?)")
$arr = explode("\n", $_POST['insert']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $sentence);
for ($arr as $sentence)
{
    $stmt->execute();
}
```